# Scanning n lines til EOF, each line containing spaces

Tags: c, input

I've been trying to search the Internet for answers but couldn't find any.

I'm trying to scan the following input:

> 100 0 1 3 10 3 6
>
> 101 0 4 4 2
>
> 200 1 2 5 1 2 3
>
> 300 1 7 6 1

Each line as a string and each string has whitespace between numbers.
I tried using:

```
while(scanf("%[^\n]s", str) != EOF)
```

but it's stuck in an infinite loop. It only scans the first line.
I also tried `fgets` until EOF but that gives me a compile error saying that I cannot compare a pointer
to an integer.
I just want to scan each line -> run it to a parser so I can separate the numbers into different variables -> do my calculations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `[^\n]` part then.

Comment: It's stuck in an infinite loop because the newline where you told it to stop is still in the input buffer. But format `"%s"` will filter leading whitespace for you. (And so would `" %[^\n]"` if you put that leading space into it). Note: the format is `%[]` not `%[]s` which is a beginner's hybrid.

Comment: "it only scans the first line" --> Not quite.  It scanned all but the trailing `'\n'` of the line.  Using `"%[^\n]s"` again will not read the `'\n'`. `'\n'` remains - forever.  Need to use different code.

Comment: `fgets()` is well suited to read a _line_.  Consider that instead of `scanf()`.